# In the hypostatic union, is Jesus just the name of the man or of the God or of both?

Tags: christology, persons-of-the-trinity, hypostatic-union

First things first: I am not a Trinitarian.  However, I know many good people that are Trinitarians and some of them are very close to me so we'll say that I'm sympathetic to the cause.  I'm sincerely interested in knowing the answer to this (and others) query to better my understanding.

What led me to the question is the belief that many Trinitarians hold regarding the name Jesus: it only belongs to the Son.  I understand this to be a way of avoiding modalism, i.e. Jesus is not the Father.  However, the name Yahweh can apply to the Father, Son, or Spirit (correct me if I'm wrong).

So is Jesus the name of the person of God in Him, or only the man, or of both God and man?  In my mind it makes sense if it's only the man but I could be way off!

Comment: Jesus is the name of a person. That person encompasses both Deity (divine nature) and humanity (human nature). The _Person_ has a name.

Answer (score 3):

Announced to Joseph, by an angel in a dream, were the following precise words :

> And she shall bring forth son and thou shalt call his name Jesus for he shall save his people from their sins [Matthew 1:21 TR-literal]

In the event, Matthew records :

> ... she brought forth the son of her ... [Matthew 1:25 TR-literal]

'She brought forth the son of her', is the literal rendering of the Greek text. Which conveys the bringing forth of 'the son' from the woman, Mary.

The Son, is 'come out of woman' as Paul tells us in Galatians.

> God sent forth his Son, come out of woman, come under law [Galatians 4:4 TR-literal]

Again, the literal rendering of Paul's words indicates that the Son is 'come out of (it is *ek*) woman.

Thus is come the Son of God.

And thus come, in humanity, the name is applied to the Person who is, at once, both Son of God, yet also brought forth of Mary, come out of woman ; thus also humanity.

Thou shalt call his name 'Jesus' refers to this Person, the Son of God, brought forth of the virgin.

The name of that Person, fully divine, fully human - is 'Jesus'.

Thus is his Person known, to them that know him - 'Jesus'.

It is not the name of *part* of a person.

It is the name of *a Person.*

---

. . . ετεκεν . . . . . .τον υιον . . . .αυτης . . . . .τον πρωτοτοκον  [TR Stephens 1550]

she brought forth . . .  the son . . .  of her . . .  the prototokos

Matthew 1:25, TR, literal

Comment: Thank you! Just for clarification...given my "multiple choice" options for the answer, you are saying that Jesus is the name of both God and man since the person encompasses both? And the Son did not have the name Jesus before the incarnation?

Comment: @Aleph-Gimel   The name 'Jesus' was given from heaven by the angel Gabriel at the time of conception. I repeat, the name is that of a _Person_. The question erroneously tries to name a _part_ of a person.

Comment: Got it, thank you.  And you agree that the Father, Son, and HS can all be called Yahweh/YHWH/Jehovah while only the Son can be called Jesus?  Is this a standardized belief among Trinitarians?

Comment: @Aleph-Gimel I totally disagree with your statement concerning the name 'Jehovah'. That is a different subject, however and that requires a fresh question. The Father is not known until the Son reveals Him.

Comment: No problem - I assume that's already a question around here somewhere.  Appreciate your feedback, Nigel.

Comment: @Aleph-Gimel I suggest you peruse the archives and also read Athanasius, for yourself, rather than just follow what the generality propagate. [Link to Athanasius](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf204.html).

Comment: Yes, I have read some of him..and did a search here before posting my question.  I know it sounds strange but I actually am more interested in what folks believe in general.

Comment: @Aleph-Gimel That's a shame.  What 'most folks believe in general' is - invariably - a broad way which leads to destruction, as Jesus tells us.

Comment: Yes, of course, I don't mean to say that I'm not interested at all in this other aspect of the question.  I'm just more interested in what the general Christian population believes in connection with this particular question.